# File upload profile avatar

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a social network site and I've been watching tutorials  where the users can upload their profile picture and change their avatar. However, whenever I try to upload a picture it gives me an error 'File upload failed' I'm not very sure how to fix it or what exactly to do. Where exactly do I need to dump all the pictures the users have uploaded?

photo_system.php

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_FILES["avatar"]["name"]) && $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"] != ""){
        $fileName = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
        $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
        $fileType = $_FILES["avatar"]["type"];
        $fileSize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
        $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["avatar"]["error"];
        $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
        $fileExt = end($kaboom);
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);


        $sql = "SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $avatar = $row[0];
        if($avatar != ""){
            $picurl = "../user/$log_username/$avatar"; 
            if (file_exists($picurl)) { unlink($picurl); }
        }
        $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../user/$log_username/$db_file_name");
        if ($moveResult != true) {
            header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: File upload failed");
            exit();
        }
```

user.php

```
$profile_pic = "";
$profile_pic_btn = "";
$avatar_form = "";

// Check to see if the viewer is the account owner
$isOwner = "no";
if($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true){
    $isOwner = "yes";
    $profile_pic_btn = '<a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="toggleElement(\'avatar_form\')">Toggle Avatar Form</a>';
    $avatar_form  = '<form id="avatar_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="php_parsers/photo_system.php">';
    $avatar_form .=   '<h4>Change your avatar</h4>';
    $avatar_form .=   '<input type="file" name="avatar" required>';
    $avatar_form .=   '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>';
    $avatar_form .= '</form>';
}
```

Comment: Do you have enctype in form.
`<form name="" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Yes, I do. $avatar_form  = '<form id="avatar_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="php_parsers/photo_system.php">';

Comment: same name of the file already exist. you can delete/rename the file already exists file.

Comment: Is the problem on the form or the location of the uploaded file?

Comment: Yeah may be. $log_username??

Comment: I added the users.php I'm not sure if it helps. That's where the $log_username came from

Comment: You will most likely get more and/or more qualified help if you narrow down the problem to the relevant code lines. I - personally - don't like to search through other person's sourcecode in order to find the error.

Comment: simply you give file name only, After its getting uploaded, v wil do furthur.ex: $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($db_file_name");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create directory first if not exist

```
  if($avatar != ""){
           $picurl = "../user/$log_username/$avatar"; 
           if (file_exists($picurl)) { unlink($picurl); }
               if(!file_exists($picurl)){
                  mkdir($picurl, 0777,true);
               }
     }
```